# What's the role of Change-Id in commit message

Tags: gerrit

Why Change-Id is important for gerrit ? What kind of problems it may have without Change-Id in the commit message ? We are using Change-Id in our commit message, but without knowing the exact reason. Our client wants to remove the Change-Id from commit message, they feel it doesn't contain any valuable information for the commit itself. So now I need to convince them the necessity of it. Could you please help ?

Answer (score 1):

It is neccessary to group the different patch sets (versions) of a change together. Otherwise there is no reason between the first commit and its overworked versions. So although there's an option "Require Change-Id", which can be deactivated, it is *strongly* adviced to not do so. See also in the [Gerrit Docs](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-changeid.html).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have seen the document and do a little exercise. There is another way to group the commit while uploading, that is using $git push refs/changes/<gerrit-id>. That also groups the changes even they have different Change-Id. Gerrit Docs tells about refs/for/* but it doesn't tell about refs/changes/<gerrit-id> ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: Not sure, if that is in the docs, but yes, I've heard about that before. I did not mention it as I don't think it's a good idea to use this. The manual work is error-prone.. life can be easier with the Change-Id

Comment: It is sure that if we use refs/for/*, Change-Id is mandatory to group them. However, I have seen the huge uses of refs/changes/<gerrit-id> too. So better to add Change-Id for avoiding mistake when using refs/for/*. This is what I feel.